# Why are both 感心する and 感心させられる useable in Xに感心+V?

Tags: grammar

In the same dictionary (研究社), I found two examples that seem to say the thing. However, one uses する while the other, させられる。

> あの子の勉強ぶりには感心する
> I'm very impressed by how this kid studies.

> いつもながら, 彼女の仕事ぶりには感心させられる
> As usual, the way she works is impressive.

How can both active and causative form be plugged into the same grammatical slot, without a change in meaning?

Comment: It's not simply causative. It's called 使役受身 (causative-passive) and has two major and quite different usages. In this case, it is used to talk about how something naturally makes you feel in a certain way. 感心する puts more emphasis on the person that does the 感心 and there's an either express or implied subject. 感心させられる, on the other hand, stresses how the object or target of 感心 naturally makes people feel that way.

Comment: Also I think you meant 感心 instead of 関心. I've edited the title accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice! What threw me off was that <誰か>に ("by someone") usually appears only after the plain form is converted to causative passive / causative / passive form. I guess 感心する already carries a bit of that "by someone" semantics, and so it has the <誰か>に even in the plain form. So perhaps the distinction between する and させられる here is slightly less strong than in cases such as 食べる or 勉強する.

Answer (score 2):

に in the first sentence can be understood as indicating the target of the subject’s emotion, or what it is directed towards.

> あの子の勉強ぶりには感心する。

When the subject is the person as in this example, English expresses a relationship like this using the passive voice. Japanese uses the active voice. If you ignore this difference in voice, に roughly corresponds to a preposition such as “by” and “with.” With verbs for some other emotions, “at” is also used, and this might bring up a closer image to に than “by” or “with.”

I don’t know what grammatical explanation is given to this, but に in the second sentence could be seen as having a dual function. Let’s use the following modified version of the first sentence as an example.

> あの子の勉強ぶりには感心させられる。

The first, probably primary, role is as the marker of the agent of the action described by the verb in the passive, which in this case is the causative 感心させる. This sentence is very similar in construction to the English translation for the first, with the transitive verb 感心させる being the direct translation of the verb “to impress,” which is used in the passive, and に playing a similar role to “by.”

> I'm very impressed **by** how this kid studies.

On the other hand, this に could also be seen as playing the same role as に in the first sentence. When something impresses you, the emotion that results is directed towards that thing. The two are one and the same.

Either way, yes, に can be used in both. The first sentence with する sounds more direct and assertive to me with focus on how the speaker feels. The second with させられる sounds to me as if the speaker is trying to sound objective shifting focus to what impresses them, rather than how they feel.